# How to change an Id on another page as it loads through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I want for the user to click a button which leads to another page. Depending on what button the user clicks, the page content should look different despite being on the same page. A simplified example is below:

Starting page html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="second-page.html" onclick="changeContent('Option One')">Click Here</a>

    <a href="second-page.html" onclick="changeContent('Option Two')">Click Here</a>
<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

second-page.html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <p id="content-id">*CONTENT SHOULD BE LOADED HERE BASED OFF BUTTON CLICKED*</p>

<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

script.js code:

```
function changeContent(n) {
     document.getElementById("content-id").innerHTML = n;
}
```

The above code does not work. I'm guessing the browser doesn't see the content-id on the first page and fails to change anything before loading the second page. Any way to reference the right id on the right page using JavaScript (no jQuery) when the new page is loaded?

Comment: If you ever wanted to try ReactJS this is the perfect oportunity. Using react you can achieve your goal easily while making any transition/content changes very smooth. If you need a basic react tutorial you can search for LearnWebCode on youtube (I hope this is not against stackoverflow rules).

Answer (score 1):

**Edited -**

Added 3 working examples that can be copy and pasted.

**Problem -**

Display content on a new view based on the button clicked to get to that view.

**Approach -**

You can store the value of ID in the browser to help identify the content that should be displayed in many ways. I will show you three working examples.

**Notes -**

I am over complicating this a little to show you how you might make this work since I do not know the exact circumstances you are working with. You should be able to use this logic to refactor for your requirements. You will find the following 3 solutions below.

**1. Using GET Params**

- Uses the GET params in the URL to help you track necessary changes in your view.

**2. Using Session Storage**

- A page session lasts as long as the browser is open, and survives over page reloads and restores.
- Opening a page in a new tab or window creates a new session with the value of the top-level browsing context, which differs from how session cookies work.
- Opening multiple tabs/windows with the same URL creates sessionStorage for each tab/window.
- Closing a tab/window ends the session and clears objects in sessionStorage.

**3. Using Local Storage**

- The difference between localStorage and sessionStorage is the time the data persists. LocalStorage spans multiple windows and lasts beyond the current session.
- The memory capacity may change by browser.
- Similar to cookies, localStorage is not permanent. The data stored within it is specific to the user and their browser.

**Solutions -**

**Working Examples -** (*Copy and paste any of the below solutions into an HTML file and they will work in your browser.*)

**Using GET Params**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            let currentURL = window.location.href.split("?")[0];

            function appendParams(val) {
                if (val === "a") {
                    window.location.assign(currentURL + "?id=a");
                }

                if (val === "b") {
                    window.location.assign(currentURL + "?id=b");
                }
            }
        </script>
        <title>Working Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="appendParams('a')">Click Here</button>
        <button onclick="appendParams('b')">Click Here</button>
        <p id="replace-id"></p>
    </body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
    let url_str = window.location.href;
    let url = new URL(url_str);
    let search_params = url.searchParams;
    let id = search_params.get("id");

    document.getElementById("replace-id").id = id;

    let ContentOne = "Some text if id is A";
    let ContentTwo = "Some text if id is B";

    if (id === "a") {
        document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = ContentOne;
    }

    if (id === "b") {
        document.getElementById("b").innerHTML = ContentTwo;
    }
</script>
```

**Using Session Storage**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            sessionStorage.setItem("id", "default");

            function addSessionStorage(val) {
                sessionStorage.setItem("id", val);
                updateContent();
            }

            function updateContent() {
                let id = sessionStorage.getItem("id");

                let ContentOne = "Some text if id is A";
                let ContentTwo = "Some text if id is B";

                if (id === "a") {
                    document.getElementById("replace-content").innerHTML =
                        ContentOne;
                }

                if (id === "b") {
                    document.getElementById("replace-content").innerHTML =
                        ContentTwo;
                }
            }
        </script>
        <title>Working Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="addSessionStorage('a')">Click Here</button>
        <button onclick="addSessionStorage('b')">Click Here</button>
        <p id="replace-content">Default Content</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Using Local Storage**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <script type="text/javascript">
            localStorage.setItem("id", "default");

            function addLocalStorage(val) {
                localStorage.setItem("id", val);
                updateContent();
            }

            function updateContent() {
                let id = localStorage.getItem("id");

                let ContentOne = "Some text if id is A";
                let ContentTwo = "Some text if id is B";

                if (id === "a") {
                    document.getElementById("replace-content").innerHTML =
                        ContentOne;
                }

                if (id === "b") {
                    document.getElementById("replace-content").innerHTML =
                        ContentTwo;
                }
            }
        </script>
        <title>Working Example</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="addLocalStorage('a')">Click Here</button>
        <button onclick="addLocalStorage('b')">Click Here</button>
        <p id="replace-content">Default Content</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how you would implement this. Can you make a JSbin?

Comment: @GabrieleScottodiVettimo I edited my answer to show you 3 working examples that you can copy and paste. Using GET params, SessionStorage and LocalStorage. Hope this helps.

Comment: @GabrieleScottodiVettimo did you ever get this working? Or did you still need help?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: there are several approaches, the easier that comes to mind is to use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) if you're dealing with [same origin](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy#Origin_determination_rules) pages

What you need is to have user information available across multiple pages. So, unlike `sessionStorage`, `localStorage` allows to store data and save it across browser sessions:

> localStorage is similar to sessionStorage, except that while localStorage data has no expiration time, sessionStorage data gets cleared when the page session ends — that is, when the page is closed.

To use it, consider adapting your javascript of first page:

```
function changeContent(n) {
     localStorage.setItem('optionChosen', n);
}
```

Then retrieve it in the second page's javascript.

```js
var opt = localStorage.getItem('optionChosen')
var content = document.querySelector('#content-id')

if (opt == null) console.log("Option null")
 
if (opt === 'Option One') content.innerText = "Foo"
if (opt === 'Option Two') content.innerText = "Bar"
```

Comment: The javascript of the first page won't work because there is o "content-id" on the first page.

Comment: Oh, indeed. Please ignore this line